# Implementing filterable table script in mediawiki?

Tags: javascript, css, mediawiki, jquery-ui-sortable

This person has managed to integrate a script (from here http://www.javascripttoolbox.com/lib/table/documentation.php) into their mediawiki.

See: [http://offene-naturfuehrer.de/web/Kategorie:Filtertabellen](http://offene-naturfuehrer.de/web/Kategorie%3aFiltertabellen)

I don't understand how they've done it!

The original script to create filterable tables is linked to on that page. Yet I have no idea how they've utilized it as they've not called it in the header..

I really want to use a filterable table like this in my mediawiki site. What do I do?!

Comment: maybe you should try taking a look at the source code? Its javascript so its not like its hidden....

Answer (score 1):

They have added some lines of code (search for `Table Filter/Sort`, far below) to the [MediaWiki:Common.js file](http://offene-naturfuehrer.de/web/MediaWiki%3aCommon.js), from where they load the script at [MediaWiki:SortTableFilter.js](http://offene-naturfuehrer.de/web/MediaWiki%3aSortTableFilter.js). You don't see it loaded in the DOM because they've used `jQuery.getScript`, which loads it via ajax and `eval`s then.