# Design a filter table in mediawiki

Tags: jquery, filter, datatables, mediawiki

I have a table in mediawiki and I want to have a filterable field in each column of a table; and customize the size of each column.

I tried to use:

1. Semantic wiki with Semantic Result Format. They allowed me to query and have a result table but I have a problem with the design. My table has 25 columns; so it overflow the page. How to create horizontal scrolling?
2. Datatables extension.
   https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:DataTables
   I have a problem when I add the following code into Localsetting.php

   ```
   $myResourceLoaderModule => array(
   'scripts'      => 'modules/jquery.dataTables.min.js',
   'styles'       => 'modules/jquery.dataTables.min.css',
   'dependencies' => array(
       'ext.datatables',
               // other javascript libraries...
   )
   );
   ```

My mediawiki won't load. How to add this extension into mediawiki? Can you please give me a tutorial?

3. I used the instruction on 
   [Implementing filterable table script in mediawiki?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13714490/implementing-filterable-table-script-in-mediawiki)

http://offene-naturfuehrer.de/web/MediaWiki_Diskussion:SortTableFilter.js

but it won't work.

What I have to do?

Answer (score 0):

DataTables could be a good fit for you, the problem is that you were trying to setup it as a separate (and outdated) extension when currently it's available as a semantic result format: https://www.semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Datatables_format

You'll need to have https://www.semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Semantic_Result_Formats extension installed

Comment: I used Semantic Result Format. But I want to make my table scrolls in the horizontal direction, customizing the size of my columns, and add filter field in each column. Do you know how I should start?

Comment: oh, I see, well .. I can't recall any result format that would match your needs and the datatables is the best one so far. With horizontal scrolling you may go with a simple css trick by wrapping your whole table block into `<div style="overflow-x: scroll;"></div>` this will give you horizontal scrolling , like this one http://jsfiddle.net/oz0g6he2/